# web3 how to send transaction with BNB

Tags: web3js, transfer

i'm begin working with web3.js api and i cant understand how to send transaction in BNB. According to documentation https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_sendtransaction i cant find some parameter that helps me.

Comment: You mean in BNB on BSC?

Comment: not sure. i mean i need to send BNB from my wallet to another wth web3

Comment: on which blockchain on the ethereum blockchain or on the BSC blockchain. if on the ethereum blockchain then you need to find the contract of BNB , create an instance of it using web3js and call the method transfer to create a transaction, you need also to sign that transaction with your private key.

Comment: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html